# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

So I am a newbie but working on a registration system form in flask/MYSQL

I am receiving this error (UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment)

After hours of playing with the code and research I need your help.

This is my file, please let me know if theres anything else I need to share.
thank you

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask.ext.mysqldb import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()


app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'x'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'x'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'x'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'x'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')


@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:

            # All Good, let's call the MySQL

            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
            cursor.callproc('sp_createUser',(_name,_email,_hashed_password))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

            if len(data) is 0:
                conn.commit()
                return json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
            else:
                return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
    finally:
        cursor.close()
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only define `conn` and `cursor` inside the if block checking the form values.  If the block is not entered, they're not defined, but you still try to reference them to close them anyway.  You should only call `close` on both if you've defined them.  Either move `conn =` and `cursor =` to before the if block, or move the `close` calls to within the block.

However, the bigger problem is that you're misunderstanding/overcomplicating how to use Flask-MySQLdb.  It will automatically create the connection and close it when the request is done, which also closes the cursor.  Simply use the extension as described in the [docs](https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

```
...
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.callproc('sp_createUser', (name, email, hashed_password))
data = cur.fetchall()
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Personally I would recommend using a context manager to handle opening and closing of your cursor and connection. You can achieve this fairly simply and it is cleaner and easier to debug. This also would eliminate the problem of trying to close a connection or cursor before it is opened in your giant try except block.

```
from contextlib import closing

# do a bunch of stuff prior to opening connection
with closing(mysql.connect()) as conn:
    with closing(conn.cursor()) as cursor:
        # do a bunch of stuff and don't worry about running .close()
```

You can view the docs for `closing` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing).

Using the `closing` would change your code to be something like this. Although it could use more refactoring, but that is a question for the code review site.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask.ext.mysqldb import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from contextlib import closing

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()


app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'x'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'x'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'x'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'x'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')


@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:

            # All Good, let's call the MySQL

            with closing(mysql.connect()) as conn:
                with closing(conn.cursor()) as cursor:
                    _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
                    cursor.callproc('sp_createUser',(_name,_email,_hashed_password))
                    data = cursor.fetchall()

                    if len(data) is 0:
                        conn.commit()
                        return json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
                    else:
                        return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: So i remove my finally code till the if __name__ and replace it with the code in between your comments and import the context library?

Comment: Yeah, remove the finally statement and import that library and change the opens to the with statement and you should be good.

Comment: Ah, I see. I have never used flask before but I am familiar with manual DB connections in pure python.

Comment: @JasonMartinez, switch to django. ;) https://www.djangoproject.com/ +1 for comedy

Comment: @electrometro i thought about it for a sec but i spent so much time on videos and researching how to do things with Python and flask that i refuse to give up. Eventually though i may.

Comment: I use django everyday and produce a ton of features with it. Just seems simpler. Yeah, sometime you end up fighting the framework, but in the end its better than fighting a wall. Just my two cents though. Also, Django is in python. :)